# How to maintain different schema versions?

Tags: c#, xml, oop, model, xsd

I have a business code component which exports data from the surrounding system. Therefore it fills a tree-like **DTO model** with simple types and composed types (built of these DTOs). Afterwards the whole model is flushed into an **xml file** for export.
The model requirements are coming from a standard paper and are defined by an XML schema defintion (**XSD**) from which I do generate **C# classes** (which contain also xml serialization stuff). For all of them I have created **wrapper classes** – the DTOs – which implement an **interface** (each of them), used by the business code. This is to make the code independent of the classes generated from the XSD, because I have different customers using *different versions* of the standard at the same time. Changes between versions are usually minimal, like a definition of a new field – simple or complex – or renamings and removements of existings fields.
The wrapper classes hold instances of the C# classes; reads and writes to the wrappers are instantly delegated to the backing instances.

My problem is, that currently for each new schema version I have to implement the whole DTO model again (because of the new generated C# classes); at least the class which has changed and the whole containment path up to the root. I also have to adapt the interface to fit the new requirements – and all existing implementations to fit the interface (again).
My current "solution" is to copy an existing model and adapt it to fit the new requirements. Copy-and-paste is because of the mass of classes (~50, ~5 props each class).

**Is there a solution to avoid reimplementing the model each time?**

I think the core problem is the *containment problem*: One change in the tree causes the whole containment path including the root to be re-implemented.
**Note:** The "interface" tree is in fact made of abstract classes.

Comment: My usual advice is that data binding works well when the schema is small and invariant, and works extremely badly when the schema is large or subject to change. You've chosen the wrong technology.

Comment: @MichaelKay what would be the right technology? Currently I want to refactor (or rewrite) this shame of a component. I'm only bound to the XML files, this is part of my customer's specification.

Comment: If I were doing a consulting exercise I would want to spend a couple of days studying the project requirements and constraints before making a technology recommendation, but on the information given, I would be looking to see whether it can be done using XSLT.